# Pascal code not compiling - error

Tags: pascal

I am learning pascal and my code is not compiling... Could someone help me??

I have tried in a few online compilers, but them all return an error.

Thanks in advance!

```
PROCEDURE ProcSoma (A: INTEGER, SOMA: INTEGER);
BEGIN
  SOMA:=SOMA+A;
  A:=A+1;
END;

BEGIN
VAR I,HI,SOMA:INTEGER;
HI:=31;
SOMA:=0;

FOR I:=1 TO HI STEP 1 DO
 IF (I MOD 2 = 1) THEN ProcSoma(ref I, ref SOMA)
 ELSE ProcSoma(ref I, SOMA);
WRITELN(SOMA);
END.
```

Comment: prog.pas(1,31) Fatal: Syntax error, ")" expected but "," found
Fatal: Compilation aborted

Comment: There are far more problems with your code than that single error. Please find a [Pascal tutorial](http://www.marcocantu.com/epascal/default.htm) first; there are problems with almost every line of that code, and a major logic error as well (with wanting to sometimes pass only one parameter by reference and sometimes the other one).

Answer (score 1):

In Pascal, the delimiter betweeen parameters in a procedure declaration is `;`, not `,`.